# Check if one series is subset of another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have 2 columns from 2 different dataframes. I want to check if column 1 is a subset of column 2.

I was using the following code:

```
set(col1).issubset(set(col2))
```

The issue with this is that if col1 has only integers and col2 has both integers and strings, then this returns false. This happens because elements of col2 are coerced into strings. For example,

```
set([376, 264, 365, 302]) & 
set(['302', 'water', 'nist1950', '264', '365', '376'])
```

I tried using `isin` from pandas. But if col1 and col2 are series then this gives a series of Boolean values. I want `True or False`.

How do I solve this? Is there a simpler function that I have missed?

**Edit 1**

Adding an example.

```
col1
0    365
1    376
2    302
3    264
Name: subject, dtype: int64

col2
0     nist1950
1     nist1950
2        water
3        water
4          376
5          376
6          302
7          302
8          365
9          365
10         264
11         264
12         376
13         376
Name: subject, dtype: object
```

**Edit 2**

col1 and col2 can have integers, strings, floats etc. I would like to not make any prejudgement about what is in these columns.

Comment: You could use `col1.isin(col2).all()`

Comment: I still get False.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`isin`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi19d_UzuXLAhUCQpoKHQHDCl0QFgggMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.Series.isin.html&usg=AFQjCNHEOa4btqDkFrnduWNtwXrgJ6qM6A&sig2=y9MhGreykYhx_XDhXFGrTw&bvm=bv.117868183,d.bGs) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) to check whether all of your `col1` elements contains in `col2`. For converting to numeric you could use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXjbHNzuXLAhUmCZoKHQdtB1kQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.0%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.to_numeric.html&usg=AFQjCNEfrTxTfJeoEu651_OSFlJEu3qpKg&sig2=FUJpJl06EckaEb4BjHojhg):

```
s1 = pd.Series([376, 264, 365, 302])
s2 = pd.Series(['302', 'water', 'nist1950', '264', '365', '376'])

res = s1.isin(pd.to_numeric(s2, errors='coerce')).all()

In [213]: res
Out[213]: True
```

More detailed:

```
In [214]: pd.to_numeric(s2, errors='coerce')
Out[214]:
0    302
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    264
4    365
5    376
dtype: float64

In [215]: s1.isin(pd.to_numeric(s2, errors='coerce'))
Out[215]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

*Note* `pd.to_numeric` works with pandas version `>=0.17.0` for previous you cound use `convert_objects` with `convert_numeric=True`

**EDIT**

If you prefer solution with `set` you could convert your first set to `str` as well and then compare them with your code:

```
s3 = set(map(str, s1))

In [234]: s3
Out[234]: {'264', '302', '365', '376'}
```

Then you could use `issubset` for `s2`:

```
In [235]: s3.issubset(s2)
Out[235]: True
```

or for `set(s2)`:

```
In [236]: s3.issubset(set(s2))
Out[236]: True
```

**EDIT2**

```
s1 = pd.Series(['376', '264', '365', '302'])
s4 = pd.Series(['nist1950', 'nist1950', 'water', 'water', '376', '376', '302', '302', '365', '365', '264', '264', '376', '376'])

In [263]: s1.astype(float).isin(pd.to_numeric(s4, errors='coerce')).all()
Out[263]: True
```

Comment: I still get false

col1
0    365
1    376
2    302
3    264
Name: subject, dtype: int64

col2
0     nist1950
1     nist1950
2        water
3        water
4          376
5          376
6          302
7          302
8          365
9          365
10         264
11         264
12         376
13         376
Name: subject, dtype: object

Comment: @Swetabh could you add that example for your question?

Comment: Just did. Let me know if that is sufficient.

Comment: @Swetabh works fine for me... Added example even with `str` for `s1`. You need to use `astype` for that. Or you could also use `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: Indeed it does when used with pd.to_numeric. The thing is that I am not sure if col1 or col2 will always be like this. In some other case it could be that col1 has strings and col2 does not. How do I handle this in a general way? Should I always convert both columns to strings/numeric and then compare?

Comment: I think for more general way you should use solution from **EDIT** with `set` with converting both columns to str with `astype(str)` or with `map(str, col)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` with param `indicator=True`:

```
In [3]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[376, 264, 365, 302]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'b':[302, 'water', 'nist1950', '264', '365', '376']})
df1.merge(df2, left_on='a', right_on='b', how='left',indicator=True)

Out[3]:
     a    b     _merge
0  376  NaN  left_only
1  264  NaN  left_only
2  365  NaN  left_only
3  302  302       both
```

So if you pass the cols of interest as the `left_on` and `right_on` params then the added col `_merge` will tell which of the column values exist in both dfs or `left_only`

This requires pandas version `0.17.0` and above

Comment: Do you think this approach is more general that the approach that Anton has given above?

Comment: Well this allows you to specify the criteria using left only, right only, outer etc. plus you can pass multiple columns