# Python Dataframe Pandas - Filter dataframe rows by condition issubset() on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter Dataframe rows depending whether all the items of a list are present in `criteria_a` column for a fixed value in `criteria_b` column.

For example, let's consider the following Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'criteria_a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'criteria_b': [2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9], 
                   'value': [0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8, 0.1]})

print(df)

   criteria_a  criteria_b  value
0           1           2    0.2
1           2           2    0.6
2           3           2    0.1
3           4           3    0.9
4           1           7    0.8
5           1           9    0.7
6           2           9    0.3
7           3           9    0.8
8           4           9    0.1
```

The possible values of the `criteria_a` column are `list_criteria_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I would like to create a new dataframe that extracts only the rows for which all items in the list `list_criteria_a` are present for a given `criteria_b` value.

The result for the above example would be only the last four rows:

```
   criteria_a  criteria_b  value
0           1           9    0.7
1           2           9    0.3
2           3           9    0.8
3           4           9    0.1
```

I know that we would have to use `issubset()`, but I do not know how.
It is rather similar to the post ([How do I get the index of a row in pandas if the row contains ALL items in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655995/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-a-row-in-pandas-if-the-row-contains-all-items-in-a-lis/49656072#49656072)) except that I want to filter the rows, and not outputting their index, with an extra condition.

Many thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280562/check-if-one-series-is-subset-of-another-in-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compare values per groups is best here use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with custom function for compare set by `issubset` method, output is boolean Series, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
f = lambda x: set(list_criteria_a).issubset(x)
df1 = df[df.groupby('criteria_b')['criteria_a'].transform(f)]
print (df1)
   criteria_a  criteria_b  value
5           1           9    0.7
6           2           9    0.3
7           3           9    0.8
8           4           9    0.1
```

Comment: can you please explain it breifly. :)